# How to extract total instance of a variable in a array and its first properties

Tags: javascript

I have got a fruits array as shown below

```
var fruits = [
    {
        "buyprice": "10",
        "sellprice": "11",
        "name": "pomogranate"
    },
    {
        "buyprice": "10",
        "sellprice": "11",
        "name": "apple"
    },
    {
        "buyprice": "12",
        "sellprice": "13",
        "name": "orange"
    },
    {
        "buyprice": "14",
        "sellprice": "15",
        "name": "apple"
    }

]
```

I want to find out the total counts of apple present in the array 
and the buy price and sellprice of the first element of the apple present in the array (not the last element)

I have tried it this way

```
function findnumberofaccourences(fruits, apple) {
    var a = 0;
   var buyprice;
     var sellprice 
    for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
      var name = fruits[i].name;
         buyprice = fruits[i].buyprice;
         sellprice = fruits[i].sellprice;
        if (name == apple) {
            a++;
        }
    }
     var p = { count: a, buyprice: buyprice, sellprice: sellprice }; 
    return p;
}
            var result = findnumberofaccourences(fruits, 'apple');
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

But when i run this i am getting the result as  (the buyprice and sellprice of apple's **last** element , where as i need apples **first** element )

```
{"count":2,"buyprice":"14","sellprice":"15"}
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/thkc0fpk/2/

could you please elt em know how to achive this

Comment: well update `buyprice` and `sellprice` values only if `a === 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. As Hacketo said, only grab the prices when `a == 0`.
2. Also, only grab the price for apples, rather than all fruit.
3. Calling the argument giving the fruit name to find `apple` is a bit misleading (since it could contain the string `pear`). Perhaps `fruitName` or similar instead?

Here's a minimal-changes example:

```
function findnumberofaccourences(fruits, fruitName) {
    var a = 0;
    var buyprice;
    var sellprice;
    for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        var name = fruits[i].name;
        if (name == fruitName) {                 // Only apples
            if (a == 0) {                        // Only the first
                buyprice = fruits[i].buyprice;
                sellprice = fruits[i].sellprice;
            }
            a++;
        }
    }
    var p = {
        count: a,
        buyprice: buyprice,
        sellprice: sellprice
    };
    return p;
}
var result = findnumberofaccourences(fruits, 'apple');
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

You can also simplify a fair bit, using the more-modern `forEach` and using the object you're going to return directly:

```
function findnumberofaccourences(fruits, fruitName) {
    var p = {
        count: 0,
        buyprice: undefined,
        sellprice: undefined
    };
    fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
        if (fruit.name == fruitName) {
            if (p.count == 0) {
                p.buyprice = fruit.buyprice;
                p.sellprice = fruit.sellprice;
            }
            p.count++;
        }
    });
    return p;
}
var result = findnumberofaccourences(fruits, 'apple');
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: a same, but different approach would be `Array.reduce()` with `p` as starting value.

Comment: @NinaScholz: You could, yeah, and I did that a few times before stopping doing it. In my view, that's an abusage of `reduce` (e.g., the accumulator isn't changing throughout the sequence). But abusage is in the mind of the beholder... :-)

Comment: is it just a taste or is it more than that?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I think it's right on the borderline. The semantics of a reduce operation, in my view, suggest an accumulator that can change on each iteration, such as `var sum = [1,2,3].reduce(function(acc, entry) { return acc + entry; }, 0);` Since that's not what we're doing if `p` never changes, to me that means I'm using the wrong tool for the job. But as I say, I think it's right on the edge. In a code review, for instance, I'd probably flag it for the coder the first time and then if they wanted to keep doing it, not flag it on subsequent reviews.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter apples first into an array, then retrieve the first element of this array to get the data you need.

```
var apples = fruits.filter(function (fruit) {
    return fruit.name === 'apple';
});

var p = {
    count: apples.length,
    buyprice: apples[0].buyprice,
    sellprice: apples[0].sellprice
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the array first

```
var price = {
    count: 0
};

fruits.reverse().forEach(function (fruit) {
    if (fruit.name === "apple") {
        price.count++;
        price.buyprice = fruit.buyprice;
        price.sellprice = fruit.sellprice;
    }
})

console.log(price)

// restore original order in fruits array (if you are going to use it)
fruits.reverse();
```

Note that this will reverse your array in place, so you'll need to do a `fruits.reverse()` once again to get back the fruits array elements in the original order, if you are going to use fruits further down the flow. (Thanks aduch)

Comment: It could be a good thing to reverse a copy of the array, or reverse it back to its original state

Comment: Reversing an array twice just to adjust the logic seems rather overkill.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed, it was an alternative to only reverse a copy, which is a better option in my opinion.

Comment: Agree. The reverse is just in case the array is needed - "if" this is the end of whatever the page is supposed to do, you probably won't even need the reverse. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well your code does not work as you expect, your example work only because `apple` is the last element of the array.

you need to update your for loop like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var name = fruits[i].name;

    if (name == apple) {
        if ( a === 0){
            buyprice = fruits[i].buyprice;
            sellprice = fruits[i].sellprice;
        }
        a++;
    }
}
```

It will update `buyprice` and `sellprice` only the first time for the first `apple`

Your orignal code was updating `buyprice` and `sellprice` for each element of your array